# how to increase an integer every specific minute in php

Tags: php

I need a php code that when you type (time), and a (base number), it increases by base number value, on specific time intervals.
e.g:
every 40 minutes, add 0.0001 to the base number 0.04

```
0.04  
0.0401  
0.0402
```

.....

Comment: What have you attempted ? Edit your question with details of the code that you have tried. SO is not a *free coding service*

Comment: i'm so amateur. i can code just a count up 1 to 10.

Comment: What is the purpose of your function ? You will need to read up php tutorials on internet. If you cant code basic things, then there is no use further working on software development!

Comment: it's a force, so i coudn't read toturials.

Comment: thank you for editing my text. my english is weak. i need this code to put in my website as a plugin. and just count up every 40 min

Comment: Read up on [User defined functions in PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp)

Try something based on the tutorial, and then come back with your attempt, if it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unixtime and calculate how many 40 minutes that has elapsed.

```
$start = 1537088883; //Unix time of when I started writing answer.

$elapsed = time() - $start; // elapsed seconds since start

$counts = floor($elapsed/(60*40)); // number of 40 minutes that has elapsed

echo 0.04 + (0.0001*$counts);
```

https://3v4l.org/q9Vhm

Right now it will output just 0.04, but if we manipulate the $start we will get a different output ( or just wait 40 minutes and the same code will output a different number).

https://3v4l.org/E9XWN

If you want to set a start date and time you can use strtotime to convert a human readable date to Unix time.

```
$start = strtotime("2018-09-01 09:00:00");
```

https://3v4l.org/c6g0l